# Macros missing when opening Excel file with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell-2.0

The purpose of the PowerShell script I am trying to write is - Open an excel document and run a macro. (The macro is stored in the Personal Workbook file - `personal.xlsb` and it runs successfully)

The problem - 
When the excel file is opened via PowerShell code, it opens fine but when the macro is run by calling `Run("NameOfMacro")`, I get an error stating macro not found. I try to find the macro in the opened excel file and it does not appear in the macro list. This seems to be because the `personal.xlsb` file is not loading.

So I close the excel file, open it manually, but the macro is still missing. I then manually open the `personal.xlsb` file and notice that the macro exists however the macro still does not appear in the excel file or any other excel file I open thereafter.
After a frustrating hour trying to understand why is the `personal.xlsb` file stopped loading suddenly. I noticed another thing - if I kill the `excel.exe` process that was started by the PowerShell code (via task manager window) and then open any excel document the macro is available!!

So I have narrowed down the issue to this - The macros are not available because the `Personal.xlsb` is NOT opened/loaded WHEN I open excel file via PowerShell.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening and what do I need to do to resolve this?

[Code reference](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/01/13/how-do-i-run-an-office-excel-macro-on-multiple-workbooks.aspx)

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$FilePath = "D:\DailyReport.xls"
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$excel.Visible = $true
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$excel.Run("SelectDataFromReport")
```

Error I get -

> Exception calling "Run" with "31" argument(s): "Cannot run the macro 'SelectDataFromReport'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macro
>       s may be disabled."
>       At line:18 char:11
>       + $excel.Run <<<< ("SelectDataFromReport")
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

By the way, I use the 64 bit PowerShell console by default but I also tried running the code using 32 bit console but it didn't make a difference.
In excel I have added the location as a trusted location and i have allowed excel files to be opened by default in edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call the macro within the personal.xlsb like so:

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$wbPersonalXLSB = $excel.workbooks.open("$env:USERPROFILE\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB")
$FilePath = "D:\DailyReport.xls"
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$excel.Visible = $true
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$excel.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!SelectDataFromReport")
$wbPersonalXLSB.Close()
$workbook.save()
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally did use that workaround. However i am curious to know if this is default behavior- the personal file not opening when excel is launched by PowerShell? Or is it something with my Office installation?

Comment: It appears to be the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x1 = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application 
$wb = $x1.workbooks.open("$env:C:\teste\testamacro.xlsm") 
$FilePath = "c:\teste\testamacro" 
$workbook = $x1.Workbooks.Open($FilePath) 
$x1.Visible = $true 
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)     
$x1.Run("testamacro.xlsm!SelectDataFromReport")    
$wb.Close() $workbook.save()`

$workbook.close() 
$x1.quit()
```